# How not to get "datum" as the lemma for "data" when using Spacy?

Tags: spacy, lemmatization

I've run into a quite common word "data" which gets assigned a lemma "datum" from lookups exceptions table spacy uses. I understand that the lemma is technically correct, but in today's english, "data" in its basic form is just "data".
I am using the lemmas to get a sort of keywords from text and if I have a text about data, I can't possibly tag it with "datum".
I was wondering if there is another way to arrive at plain "data" then constructing another "my_exceptions" dictionary used for overriding post-processing.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Lemminflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) which works as an add-in pipeline component for SpaCy.  It should give you better results.

To use it with SpaCy, just `import lemminflect` and call the new `._.lemma()` function on the Token, ie.. `token._.lemma()`.  Here's an example..

```
import lemminflect
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp('I got the data')
for token in doc:
    print('%-6s %-6s %s' % (token.text, token.lemma_, token._.lemma()))

I      -PRON- I
got    get    get
the    the    the
data   datum  data
```

Lemminflect has a prioritized list of lemmas, based on occurrence in corpus data.  You can see all lemmas with...

```
print(lemminflect.getAllLemmas('data'))

{'NOUN': ('data', 'datum')}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy to customize the lemmatizer once you know where to look. The original lemmatizer tables are from the package [spacy-lookups-data](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-lookups-data) and are loaded in the model under `nlp.vocab.lookups`. You can use a local install of `spacy-lookups-data` to customize the tables for new/blank models, but if you just want to make a few modifications to the entries for an existing model, you can modify the lemmatizer tables on the fly.

Depending on whether your pipeline includes a tagger, the lemmatizer may be referring to rules+exceptions (with a tagger) or to a simple lookup table (without a tagger), both of which include an exception that lemmatizes `data` to `datum` by default. If you remove this exception, you should get `data` as the lemma for `data`.

#### For a pipeline that includes a tagger (rule-based lemmatizer)

```
# tested with spaCy v2.2.4
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# remove exception from rule-based exceptions
lemma_exc = nlp.vocab.lookups.get_table("lemma_exc")
del lemma_exc[nlp.vocab.strings["noun"]]["data"]

assert nlp.vocab.morphology.lemmatizer("data", "NOUN") == ["data"]

# "data" with the POS "NOUN" has the lemma "data"
doc = nlp("data")
doc[0].pos_ = "NOUN" # just to make sure the POS is correct
assert doc[0].lemma_ == "data"
```

#### For a pipeline without a tagger (simple lookup lemmatizer)

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")

# remove exception from lookups
lemma_lookup = nlp.vocab.lookups.get_table("lemma_lookup")
del lemma_lookup[nlp.vocab.strings["data"]]

assert nlp.vocab.morphology.lemmatizer("data", "") == ["data"]

doc = nlp("data")
assert doc[0].lemma_ == "data"
```

#### For both: save model for future use with these modifications included in the lemmatizer tables

```
nlp.to_disk("/path/to/model")
```

Also be aware that the lemmatizer uses a cache, so make any changes before running your model on any texts or you may run into problems where it returns lemmas from the cache rather than the updated tables.